# Auto import for shared libs not working in NX

Tags: typescript, next.js, shared-libraries, monorepo, nx-monorepo

Created an NX monorepo with a shared library in nextjs, typescript (`"@nx/next": "16.5.1",`). Components that are located in the shared library can be imported in the main app by writing the import statement manually, like so:
`import { Typography } from '@frontend/jsx-core';`

But I don't want to write the import statement each time, but can't figure it out how it can be suggested by the auto-import of vscode. I have an older project where it works   `"@nrwl/next": "15.6.3"`. So it should be possible..

I doubt it's a vscode setting, because it works in the old project, but not in the new one. Also created a new project with `"@nrwl/next": "15.6.3"`, to see if that works. But that has the same problem. So I'm really wondering why the import is suggested in the old project but not in the new created ones.

New project without auto suggested imports (branch: feature/shared-lib): https://github.com/RowinVanAmsterdam/gamesource

Old project:
https://github.com/koiosonline/koios.world--leg

Also checked every config file if I could see any difference and tried to copy over. But so far no luck.

One more note, as soon as I imported a shared component manually, and want to add an additional shared component, the auto-import/suggestion works. It asks to update the already existing import.

ts.config.json:

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@frontend/jsx-core": ["libs/jsx-core/src/index.ts"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

ts.config.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx",
    "../../apps/platform/.next/types/**/*.ts",
    "../../dist/apps/platform/.next/types/**/*.ts",
    "next-env.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jest.config.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "jest.config.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "src/**/*.spec.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.js",
    "src/**/*.spec.js",
    "src/**/*.test.jsx",
    "src/**/*.spec.jsx",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue fixed itself, created another project without any issues and the problem never existed after that.